# user groups in quicksight and filtering data based on group

Tags: amazon-quicksight

I am using quicksight and am having many dashboards but I want to restrict the access to the data in the dashboards based on the group(role) to which the user is assigned So what I am asking is should I for each group create the dashboards that he could access or can I apply some filtering based on the user group when he accesses the dashboard

Comment: Hi Khalil. I'm facing the same issue, were you able to find a solution for this?

Comment: yes, to solve this issue, I had to use the AWS CLI to create the groups like shown in the documentation here [link](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/quicksight/latest/user/managing-users.html#creating-quicksight-groups). First you need to create the groups by using `aws quicksight create-group` then you need to assign your users to the different groups with `aws quicksight create-group-membership` and later on, you go to the AWS Quicksight in console and when you share any new dashboard, you type the group name (because you won't find the groups listed) instead of users and that worked for me!